# Existe no português uma palavra para indicar Suástica com as pontas viradas para a esquerda?

Tags: palavra-para-ideia

A [suástica](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Su%C3%A1stica) é um símbolo místico utilizado em diferentes culturas e religiões. Sua versão mais conhecida (provavelmente por influência da super-exposição causada pelo partido nacional socialista da Alemanha surgido nos anos 1930) é a que possui as pontas viradas no sentido horário (como [esta](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cf/Flag_of_the_NSDAP_(1920%E2%80%931945).svg/2000px-Flag_of_the_NSDAP_(1920%E2%80%931945).svg.png)).

Descobri recentemente que existe em alguns idiomas (tais como o francês [*sauvastika*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sauvastika), o inglês [*sauwastika*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sauwastika) e até mesmo o [sauvástica](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sauv%C3%A1stica) do espanhol) uma palavra que indica a suástica onde as pontas estão viradas no sentido anti-horário (como [esta](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ab/Indian_Swastika.svg/145px-Indian_Swastika.svg.png?uselang=fr)). Intuí que se tal termo existisse no Português seria *sauvástica* ou *sauástica*, mas estranhamente pesquisei por [sauvástica](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/sauv%C3%A1stica) e [sauástica](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/sau%C3%A1stica) no Priberam e no Michaelis ([1](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=0&t=0&palavra=sauv%C3%A1stica) e [2](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=0&t=0&palavra=sau%C3%A1stica)) e não parecem existir tais termos.

Minha pergunta é: existe uma palavra no idioma de Camões e Machado de Assis que signifique uma suástica levógira, isto é, com as pontas para a esquerda?

Comment: Nem o Houaiss tem essas palavras.

Comment: Tem *esvástica*, mas é o mesmo que *suásticca*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não.
Em português, "*suástica*" designa tanto a versão horária (dextrogira) como a versão anti-horária (levogira).

Tem como sinónimos "cruz gamada" e "*[esvástica](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/esv%C3%A1stica)*".
A palavra "*esvástica*" é incomum, nunca a tinha ouvido.

Não existe equivalente ao espanhol "sauvástica".
O termo alternativo "suástica-esquerda" parece ser usado por vezes, como por exemplo n[o artigo da Wikipédia sobre a suástica](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Su%C3%A1stica), mas nunca o tinha ouvido.
Tem muito poucos resultados em pesquisas online, cerca de 150, mas isso pode ser por ser um conceito raramente usado.